# Who to contact for YouTube Content ID API for the purpose of developing new web tools?

Tags: youtube-api

I am aware of the partnership program in order to gain access to the YouTube Content ID API, but I'm not interested in monetization. I'd like to work with the API to develop a web tool. Is there any way to do this? I'm having a hard time trying to contact YouTube about it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can contact them through [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/).

> The YouTube Content ID API is intended for use by YouTube content
>   partners and is not accessible to all developers or to all YouTube
>   users. If you do not see the YouTube Content ID API as one of the
>   services listed in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/), see
>   [www.youtube.com/partner](https://www.youtube.com/partner) to learn more about the YouTube Partner
>   Program.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It's looking more and more like I cannot complete the API request unless I'm a partner. It's a shame that they do not allow emails except for specific inquiries or for partners.